# Quirk in UIActivityViewController integration

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I integrated a sharing option into my app and everything seems fine, basically I excluded every type of UIActivity except for Message, Twitter, and Facebook, and when I tested to see if it functions, what I see in the text box is

> "I got a new highscore!
>
> com.apple.UIKit.activity.Message
>
> com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToFacebook
>
> com.apple.UiKit.activity.PostToTwitter".

and the text appears in each of activities.

Is there anyway to remove the text, or is it supposed to be that way?

Here is a method in my MainViewController which presents the UIActivityViewController.

```
-(void)sharedView {

APActivityProvider *APActivityPro = [[APActivityProvider alloc] init];

NSArray *activites = @[APActivityPro,UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter];

activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activites applicationActivities:nil];

activityController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                            UIActivityTypeMail,
                                            UIActivityTypePrint,
                                            UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                            UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                            UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                            UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                            UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                            UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                            UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
                                            UIActivityTypeAirDrop];

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];

[activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)
 {

    if (completed)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                        message:NSLocalizedString(@"Post Sent!",@"the confirmation of the sent message/post")
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"done")
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
 ]; 
}
```

And also my code in my APActivityProvider.m file.

```
-(id) activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController*)activityViewController

     itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType

{

if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage])
    
    return NSLocalizedString(@"I got a new highscore!",@"Comment for message");

if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook])
    
    return NSLocalizedString(@"I got a new highscore!",@"Comment for Facebook");

if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter])
    
    return NSLocalizedString(@"I got a new highscore!",@"Comment for twitter");

return nil;
}

- (id) activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)

activityViewController

{
return @"";
}
```

Comment: I think we're going to need to see some source code in order to give you answer.

Comment: @onnoweb  I added in the code relevant to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear you are using the API incorrectly. Specifically:

```
NSArray *activites = @[APActivityPro,UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter];

activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activites applicationActivities:nil];
```

Activity Items are your content (Strings, Images, etc) while applicationItems are the custom activity options you add to the default system ones (something you code such as an open in app store activity). You do not need to tell the UIActivityViewController what system activities you want. All are enabled by default.

For an example of how to use this API, I have included the following:

```
NSNumber *AppStoreID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:550008982];

NSArray *activityItems =
@[ AppStoreID ];

NSArray *applicationActivities =
@[ [ATFAppStoreActivity alloc] ];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                  applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here, I have my subclassed UIActivity (ATFAppStoreActivity) that takes an NSNumber to display the App Store page for that app.

Comment: Thank you, it completely solved my problem. I would vote up, if I actually had enough rep.